# I have been trying to upload multiple files

Tags: php

I have been trying to upload multiple files and moving to different folder, files are uploaded and moved but the format is .tmp so, how can it be changed?

```
$tree3=getcwd();

echo $tree3;

foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $filename)
{
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename2)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($filename, $tree3.'/'.basename($filename));
    }
}
```

Comment: because you're naming them $filename, as assignment of `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` have you tried passing basename($filename2)?

Comment: yes tried with basename($filename2) it only makes the file with uploaded format but no content in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this-

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

For more info : https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file

Comment: thank you! but if you can suggest any solution for this syntax it would be much helpful.